# How to do a while loop in LISP

Tags: loops, while-loop, lisp, common-lisp

I cannot get a simple while loop to work in lisp!

```
(loop (while (row >= 0))
      setf(row (- row 1))
      (collect (findIndex row col))
```

while row is more or equal to 0 i want to decrement row and collect the result given by findIndex method.
Suppose the col is given.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 19):

The correct form of the loop is the following:

```
(loop while (>= row 0) 
  do (setf row (- row 1))           ; or better: do (decf row)
  collect (findIndex row col))
```

For a detailed description of the loop syntax, see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_a.htm).

Answer (score 4):

If you count down, you don't need `WHILE`+decrement.

Your loop goes from `row - 1` down to `-1`. We can write it as a `FOR` loop. Here are two examples:

```
(loop for row-number from (1- row) downto -1
      collect (find-index row-number col)))
```

If you want to count down from `row` to `0` (here using `downfrom ... to` instead of `from ... downto`):

```
(loop for row-number downfrom row to 0
      collect (find-index row-number col)))
```