# Lisp Loop Largest Number

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp

I've been fiddling with Lisp programs for a little while and one thing that I can never seem to figure out is how to use a loop on a list inside a function. I'm trying to create a function that will take a list as the parameters while using a do... loop. I know how to do it with if statements but now I need to use a loop. Does anyone have a clue on how to do that?

```
(defun maximum (a_list)
  (if (= (length a_list) 1)
      (car a_list)
      (if (> (car a_list) (maximum (cdr a_list)))
          (car a_list)
          (maximum (cdr a_list))))
    (format t "~d" a_list))
```

Here's what I have so far on the if statements. They might not work right but at least they work.

Comment: Can you add the code for the if statements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a while loop in LISP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739365/how-to-do-a-while-loop-in-lisp)

Comment: @rsjaffe No. I need to use a do loop. The while loop doesn't give me the right answer.

Comment: The code you show is apparently not an attempt to do it with a do...loop, but this is not a working recursive version either. The maximize function shown here always return (due to format); besides you call length at each step of recursion.

Comment: *** typo, the function returns nil (due to format returning nil)

Comment: `loop` examples and how to get the max or min of a list: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html#max-min

Answer (score 2):

Here another set of possibilities, in addition to those proposed in another answers.

First of all, when writing a function, one should also test for special cases, while you do not check for an empty list. So the structure of the function could be something of this type:

```
(defun maximum (l)
  (if (null l)
      nil        ; or give an error
      ...normal solution...))
```

In case of returning `nil`, this structure in Common Lisp is identical to the following one, given that `and` evaluates its arguments in sequence, and returns `nil` as soon as an argument is evaluated to `nil`, otherwise returns the value of the last argument:

```
(defun maximum (l)
  (and l ...normal solution...))
```

Here the alternative solutions.

Without loop or recursion, with predefined functions `reduce` ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm#reduce)) and `max` ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_max_m.htm#max)).

```
(defun maximum (l)
  (and l (reduce #'max l)))
```

With the construct `dolist` ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm#dolist)), that iterates a variable over a list:

```
(defun maximum (l)
  (and l (let ((result (car l)))
           (dolist (x (cdr l) result)
             (when (> x result)
               (setf result x))))))
```

And finally, with a compact version of `do` ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm#do)):

```
(defun maximum (l)
  (and l (do ((maximum-so-far (car l) (max (pop l) maximum-so-far)))
             ((null l) maximum-so-far))))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `loop` the solution is trivial:

```
(loop for x in '(1 2 7 4 5) maximize x)
```

I assume therefore that what you intend to do is to write the function with a `do`  loop. In this case you have to traverse the list keeping track of the maximum element so far, and updating this value if you find a larger value:

```
(setq list '(1 2 7 4 5))

(do* ((l list (cdr l)) 
      (x (car l) (car l)) 
      (max x) ) 
     ((null l) max) 
 (if (> x max) 
   (setq max x) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun maximum (list)
  (let ((result)) ;; short for ((result nil))
    (dolist (x list)
      (if result
          (when (> x result)
            (setf result x))
          (setf result x)))
    result))
```

`(dolist (x list) ... )` is like Python's `[... for x in list]`

It is typical imperative style to create a variable with
`let` and `setf` to it to change its value.