# How to do a While loop in Common LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Hi I am new in Common Lisp and there aren't any tutorials I can find that relates to my current problem, I have decent knowledge in Java and I tried converting simple programs from Java to Common LISP as an exercise and one particular thing I can't do is a while loop, how do I do it? it always results in UNDEFINED-FUNCTION

**TL;DR**

how do I do a while loop in common LISP with certain conditions like in Java like this:

```
while(UserIn > 0)
{
    LastD = UserIn % 10;
    Sum = Sum + LastD;
    Product = Product * LastD; 
    UserIn = UserIn / 10;
}


if (Sum == Product) 
{
    System.out.println("\nGiven number is a Spy number");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("\nGiven number is not a Spy number");
}
```

my attempt in common LISP is as follows

```
  (while (> userIn 0)
        (setq LastD(mod 10 UserIn))
        (setq Product(* LastD Product))
        (setq Sum(+ LastD Sum))
        (setq UserIn(/ UserIn 10)))
    
    (terpri)
    
    (if (= a b)
    (format t "is a spy number")
    (format t "is not a spy number"))
    )
    (Spynumber)
```

and it keeps on saying: debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION, thank you!

Comment: You can learn iteration by example here: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html

Comment: TXR Lisp: [`(defun spy-number-p (integer) (let ((digs (digits integer))) (= (+ . digs) (* .
 digs))))`](https://pastebin.com/D0DTrSie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example program in Java assigns variables that are not declared in the current scope. You have the same problem in Lisp, where you call `setq` on variables that are not declared. You need to declare variables in Lisp otherwise the behavior is unspecified.

One way to declare variables is to have a `let` block:

```
(let ((product 1)
      (sum 0))
   ...

   (setq sum (+ sum d)) ;; <-- here SETQ is well-defined

   ...)
```

Also, you compute both quotient and the remainder of a division: in Common Lisp functions can return more than one values, and in particular, `truncate` divides and returns the remainder as a secondary value:

```
(multiple-value-bind (q r) (truncate u 10)

   ...)
```

#### Recursive approach

It is possible to write loops as recursive procedures, and your example is one of the cases where I find the recursive approach easier to understand. Let's define `spy-compute` a function of three arguments: a number, the current sum, and the current product of the remainders:

```
(defun spy-compute (u s p)
  ...)
```

The base case corresponds to `(= u 0)`, and in this case the function returns both the sum and the product, as two values:

```
(defun spy-compute (u s p)
  (if (= u 0)
      (values s p)
      ...))
```

The generat case of recursion consists in dividing u by 10, and calling `spy-number` recursively with modified sum and products:

```
(defun spy-compute (u s p)
  (if (= u 0)
      (values s p)
      (multiple-value-bind (q r) (truncate u 10)
        (spy-compute q (+ s r) (* p r)))))
```

This functions needs to be called with the sum initialized to 0 and the product initialized to 1. You can provide a simpler interface to the caller:

```
(defun spy (n)
  (spy-compute n 0 1))
```

<sup>(I fixed a bug here, I had 0 and 1 reversed)</sup>

And if you want to check if the number is a spy number, you can define this functions (the `p` suffix is for "predicate", the naming convention for functions that returns a boolean value):

```
(defun spyp (n)
  (multiple-value-bind (s p) (spy n)
    (= s p)))
```

Example

Having the three functions defined as above, let's trace them and check if 1124 is a spy number (spoiler alert, it is):

```
* (trace spy-compute spy spyp)
* (spyp 1124)
```

Here is the execution trace, I added comments manually:

```
  ;; root call to SPYP with 1124
  0: (SO::SPYP 1124)
    ;; it calls SPY
    1: (SO::SPY 1124)
      ;; ... which calls SPY-COMPUTE with sum 0 and product 1
      2: (SO::SPY-COMPUTE 1124 0 1)
        ;; DIVIDE by TEN, REMAINDER is 4
        ;; RECURSE With SUM = SUM + 4 and PRODUCT = PRODUCT * 4
        3: (SO::SPY-COMPUTE 112 4 4)
          ;; DIVIDE by TEN: 112 = 11 * 10 + 2, adjust counters
          4: (SO::SPY-COMPUTE 11 6 8)
            ;; ETC.
            5: (SO::SPY-COMPUTE 1 7 8)
              ;; BASE CASE OF RECURSION, RETURN BOTH COUNTERS
              6: (SO::SPY-COMPUTE 0 8 8)
              ;; NO CHANGE IS MADE TO THE RESULT, IT BUBBLES UP
              6: SPY-COMPUTE returned 8 8
            5: SPY-COMPUTE returned 8 8
          4: SPY-COMPUTE returned 8 8
        3: SPY-COMPUTE returned 8 8
      2: SPY-COMPUTE returned 8 8
    1: SPY returned 8 8
  ;; CHECK if (= P S), which is T here
  0: SPYP returned T
```

#### Iterate

Your example can also be written using a loop. In addition other the standard ways of looping, you can also use the `iterate` package, which contrary to LOOP allows to mix the test clauses (while) with iteration clauses (for):

```
(ql:quickload :iterate) ;; see https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/

(use-package :iterate)

(defun iter-spy (n)
  (iter
    (for u :initially n :then q)
    (while (> u 0))
    (for (values q r) = (truncate u 10))
    (sum r :into s)
    (multiply r :into p)
    (finally (return
               (values s p)))))
```

Comment: does this work with userinput as well? I may have not included the whole code because it might be too long and I really don't know how to do it here in stack overflow, I tried the 1st approach and the recursive one, I still don't get it. I'm sorry I'm a newbie at programming especially in common LISP

Comment: @NikkoNeri I don't understand your question about "userinput"? I changed the answer to show a step-by-step execution of the recursive approach if that helps (I also fixed a bug :/)

Answer (score 4):

Common Lisp does not have `while` form, but it has a much more powerful
[`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm) macro which has the [`while`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ad.htm) keyword you want:

```
(loop while ... do ...)
```

See also [How to do a while loop in LISP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35739365/850781)

Comment: I read in some CL book that "loop" is not recommended for use because even ANSI standard is very ambiguous and incomplete on "loop" macro

Answer (score 3):

As someone else has said, you can use `loop` to do that, and that would be the idiomatic approach.

But Lisp is the *programmable* programming language: if you want `while`, you can have `while`:

```
(defmacro while (test &body decls/tags/forms)
  `(do () ((not ,test) (values))
     ,@decls/tags/forms))
```

And now

```
> (let ((i 0))
    (while (< i 10)
      (print i)
      (incf i)))

0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 

>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`do`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_do_do.htm) you can loop and assign variables in parallel, the syntax is:

```lisp
(do ((<var1> <var1-initial-value> <var1-step>)
     (<var2> <var2-initial-value> <var2-step>)
     ...)
    ((<exit-condition>)
     (<final-statement1>)
     (<final-statement2>)
     ...)
  (<action1-during-loop>)
  (<action2-during-loop>)
  ...)
```

So with your code, more or less:

```lisp
(let* ((UserIn (read))
       (UI UserIn))
  (do* ((LastD (rem UserIn 10) (rem UserIn 10))
        (Sum 0 (+ Sum LastD))
        (Product 1 (* Product LastD))
        (UserIn UserIn (truncate UserIn 10)))
       ((<= UserIn 0)
        (format t "~&LastD: ~f, Sum: ~f, Product: ~f, UserIn: ~f"
                LastD Sum Product UserIn)
        (if (= Sum Product)
            (format t "~&~A is Spy number" UI)
            (format t "~&~A is Not Spy number" UI)))
    (format t "~&LastD: ~f, Sum: ~f, Product: ~f, UserIn: ~f" 
            LastD Sum Product UserIn)))

> LastD: 4.0, Sum: 0.0, Product: 1.0, UserIn: 1124.0
> LastD: 4.0, Sum: 4.0, Product: 4.0, UserIn: 112.0
> LastD: 2.0, Sum: 6.0, Product: 8.0, UserIn: 11.0
> LastD: 1.0, Sum: 7.0, Product: 8.0, UserIn: 1.0
> LastD: 1.0, Sum: 8.0, Product: 8.0, UserIn: 0.0
> 1124 is Spy number
> LastD: 2.0, Sum: 0.0, Product: 1.0, UserIn: 12.0
> LastD: 2.0, Sum: 2.0, Product: 2.0, UserIn: 1.0
> LastD: 1.0, Sum: 3.0, Product: 2.0, UserIn: 0.0
> 12 is Not Spy number
```

For some code snippets you can visit http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defmacro while (condition &rest body)
  `(loop while ,condition
         do (progn
              ,@body)))
```