# Does Common Lisp have any syntactic sugar for a while True, i.e. infinite, loop?

Tags: while-loop, common-lisp, infinite-loop

Common Lisp's LOOP macro has made it notorious for having everything and the kitchen sink when it comes to looping. Despite this, `while` loops [are a bit difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35739365/10319707). Is the special case of `while true`, i.e. infinite loops, an exception? That is, does Common Lisp offer any syntactic sugar for infinite loops?

My attempts to find anything like this online have failed. [This cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html) suggests making a circular list and then telling the LOOP macro to do something for each element in that infinite list. This clearly works, but it's not any sort of syntactic sugar. For comparison, the R language lets users write `while(TRUE){...}` as `repeat{...}`. This is the sort of syntactic sugar that I have in mind.

Note: As much as I love seeing Lisp macros, I'm not asking for anyone to implement `repeat` in Common Lisp. I want to know what is already in the language from the get go.

Comment: It seems very odd to claim that `(loop while <condition> do ...)` is 'difficult': much as I dislike `loop` that's not difficult.

Comment: Hey, the Cookbook shows how to loop forever: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html#looping-forever-return maybe it lacks another sentence of explanation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [simple `LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/06_aaaa.htm) macro is an infinite loop.

```
(loop
  (print 1)
  (print 2))
```

There's an implicit block named `NIL` around the body, so you can exit the loop using `(return)`. This is the equivalent of `break` in other languages, although you can also supply a value to be used as the value of the loop expression.

Answer (score 8):

Endless loop:

```
(loop while t
      do ...)
```

above can be written shorter:

```
(loop do ...)
```

above can be written shorter:

```
(loop ...)
```

That's because `LOOP` already loops indefinitely by default.